# What is wrong with case-in statement in shell script?

Tags: shell, ksh

I'm using QNX4 *ksh86* clone and here is some simple shell-script piece that my shell interpreter is stuck on:

```bash
PWDCMD=pwd

case "`$PWDCMD`" in
//*)
    # On an Apollo, discard everything before `/usr'.
    PWDCMD="eval pwd | sed -e 's,.*/usr/,/usr/,'"
    ;;
esac
```

Syntax error on line with `//*)`.

> ./fixinc.sh[90]: syntax error

1. What is wrong?
2. How could I convert this piece to work with *ksh*?

P.S.: this is a piece of gcc build script [fixinc.sh](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/releases/gcc-3.0.0/gcc/fixinc/fixincl.sh#L87) if that helps.

Comment: Are you sure it's using ksh? The shebang says `#!/bin/sh` which means it uses POSIX sh.

Comment: Can you post the exact error message that's being printed?

Comment: It is 100% ksh86 clone (QNX4 default shell), and the message is  ```./fixinc.sh[90]: syntax error```. Note that file name differs however it is the same script just copied with 1 letter dropped. If I modify ```//*)``` part as ```"//*")``` f.e. the error is gone however I don't think that it works as intended with commas.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this script?

```
#!/bin/ksh

PWDCMD=pwd

case $($PWDCMD) in
"/"*"/"*)
    # On an Apollo, discard everything before `/usr'.
    echo "enter case"
    PWDCMD="eval pwd | sed -e 's,.*/usr/,/usr/,'"
    ;;
esac
```

If you are sure that command "pwd" get always a path with two slash then use `"/"*"/"*)` else use `"/"*)`

Let me know if it gone.

Thank you.